# My Ansible version is 2.8, yet the unique return values of the Git module are from 2.5

Tags: git, ansible

Ansible 2.5's Git module only returns a few unique return values, while the Ansible 2.8's git module returns more unique return values such as `git_dir_now`. I am running Ansible 2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and using the gid module the unique return values I get don't have `git_dir_now`.

Ansible 2.5 Git Module docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/git_module.html#id6

Ansible 2.8 Git Module docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html#id6

I have already tried completely re-installing Ansible and Git, yet no result.

```
- name: Clone repository for back-end
  git:
    repo: "git@gitlab.com:[my_repo]"
    dest: /home/ubuntu/myfolder
    version: master
    accept_hostkey: yes
  register: clonedgit
  notify: 
    - set nginx directory be
- debug: msg="{{ clonedgit }}"
```

I get these values only: 
[image]

I get these return values only, but since I'm on Ansible 2.8 I should have got other values such as `git_dir_now` too.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out why this was happening.

"git_dir_now" : "Contains the new path of .git directory if it's changed"

This means if we pass the parameter "separate_git_dir" with separate directory to clone the repo, "git_dir_now" will be returned.

I wanted this return value because I want to get the full path of the repository directory created. Different VCS create different directory names, for example GitLab adds dashes, while others do it differently.